# Finding birth/baptism record (ca 1845) for August E.F.Reichow in Germany?

Tags: germany, birth-records, baptism-records, 1840s, brandenburg

How would I find a birth/baptism record for my great grandfather (August E.F.Reichow 1845-1899) in order to identify his parents and siblings?

The timeline I have for him is:

- Left from Bremen in 1887 on the ship *Main* with:

  - Wife Charlotte Trader 1840-1907 and children:

    - son Hermann age 16
    - son Ernst/Edward age 9
    - daughter Auguste Ernestine age 7
- Arrived New York 10, May 1887
- He is buried in a plot purchased by Herman Reichow......maybe a brother?

It has been mentioned that he may have had relatives in Kraatz, Germany.

Comment: Hi. Welcome to Genealogy.SE. Please see [our tour](http://genealogy.stackexchange.com/tour) on how this site works.

Comment: What do you mean by “Kraatz was mentioned”? Is this a possible place of origin?

Comment: I've edited your question to focus it on asking a single question, which I think is the key piece of information that you are seeking.  If you wish to improve it further by adding/clarifying then there is an **edit** button beneath that can be used to do that.

Comment: Welcome to G&FH.SE!  It appears someone edited your question without explaining that you don't have to sign your posts because the system does it automatically by means of your [user card](http://genealogy.stackexchange.com/users/4167/gail-reichow-scaramuzzo?tab=profile) where you can place your email address if you wish.  I also encourage you to take the [tour], and to look at the other questions tagged "Germany".

Comment: What is your source for the arrival date and place?  According to FamilySearch (whose index could be wrong), the [Germans to America index](https://familysearch.org/ark:/61903/1:1:KDS4-NVM) shows an arrival from 10 May 1887 for the port of Baltimore. If you can get a passenger list for a Baltimore arrival for this family, you will get MUCH more information than you could from a Castle Garden (NY) arrival, which is a US Customs House list.

Answer (score 2):

The only clue we have so far is a possible place name – *Kraatz*. (Where is it mentioned?)

### possible places

There are three possible places with this name, all in eastern Germany:

1. [Kraatz](http://gov.genealogy.net/item/show/object_352512), a village in Brandenburg, now part of the city of Gransee
2. [Kraatz](http://gov.genealogy.net/item/show/KRAATZJO63UJ), a village in the north of Brandenburg, part of the municipality of Nordwestuckermark
3. [Kraatz](http://gov.genealogy.net/item/show/object_1054452), a village in northern Saxony-Anhalt, part of Arendsee

### weighing the odds

Using [Geogen](http://legacy.stoepel.net/de/), a mapping application for *todays* surname distribution, we see that a lot of people named *Reichow* live in the Uckermark district (Kraatz number 2). While no Reichow lives in the Salzwedel district (Kraatz number 3), a neighboring district (Stendal) has also a smaller, but still significant number of inhabitants with this name. No one with this name has a landline (that is where the data comes from) in Gransee (number 1).

So we should focus on Kraatz in the Uckermark (2) and Kraatz in Saxony-Anhalt (3).

### Kraatz (Uckermark, Brandenburg)

I have no information on the former parish. This would help to look up possible church book duplicates on Ancestry (collection: *Brandenburg, Germany, Zweitschriften von Kirchenbüchern, 1700-1874*). Nowadays, Kraatz belongs to Fürstenwerder and you could [ask the parish office](http://www.kirche-uckermark.de/kirchengemeinden/pfarraemter/fuerstenwerder.html) for relevant church records.

### Kraatz (Arendsee, Saxony-Anhalt)

The village belonged to the parish of Kläden. Relevant church records for Kläden, including Kraatz, are available from FamilySearch (on microfilm):

- [116662 – Kirchenbuchduplikat, 1808-1874](https://familysearch.org/search/catalog/116662?availability=Family%20History%20Library) (church book duplicate, containing baptisms, marriages and deaths)

Comment: The passenger list entry may specify Prussia or Saxony, which would add weight to one or another of the possibilities.

Comment: @bgwiehle All would be Prussia, wouldn't they?

Comment: You're right; Anhalt was Prussian starting in 1815 (Sorry for the error). I suppose one could hope for the province (Brandenburg or Saxony-Anhalt) to be named on the passenger list, but it's rarer before 1900.

Comment: @bgwiehle Kraatz (Arendsee) was Provinz Sachsen and the other two were Provinz Brandenburg, thus all part of Prussia. The territory of Anhalt however remained a duchy until 1918.